# Zend Framework. A plugin by the name "prg" was not found

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

After updating Zend Framework to 3 version I got an error on user registration page:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
File:
../vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php:142
Message:
A plugin by the name "prg" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager
```

Answer (score 0):

prg plugin was [removed](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/release-3.0.0/CHANGELOG.md) from zend-mvc package on version 3, and it should be installed separately via the [zendframework/zend-mvc-plugin-prg](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc-plugin-prg) package